# Inno Setup - Conditional Parameters

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm trying to setup a situation in InnoSetup where it will do something by default, unless a parameter is specified to do things differently. I'm using Inno Setup Processor, and am looking at providing a #defines, but it cannot be compiled without it, and supplying a #defines parameter when one already exists keeps the origional value.

Are there any other options?

Regards

Tris

Comment: Do you mean a parameter during the build of the setup file (at build time), or during the running of the setup file (at run time) ?

Answer (score 1):

Answered:

use {Param:ParamName|DefaultValue}

Figured it out eventually :)